# `which python` in virtualenvwrapper.sh screws up in arch linux

Tags: python-2.x, archlinux, virtualenvwrapper

On arch linux, after install virtualenvwrapper system-wide, via `sudo pip2 install virtualenvwrapper` and adding this in my user's .bash_profile,

```
 export WORKON_HOME=/home/myuser/.virtualenvs
 export PROJECT_HOME=/home/myuser/work
 source /usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

An error shows up whenever I launch a new shell window:-

```
which: no python in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin/core_perl)
-bash: : command not found
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader, check that virtualenv has been installed for VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON= and that PATH is set properly.
```

This can be traced to line 50 in the virtualenvwrapper.sh script:-

```
 47 # Locate the global Python where virtualenvwrapper is installed. 
 48 if [ "$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON" = "" ] 
 49 then 
 50     VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON="$(\which python)" 
 51 fi
```

And is a result of the conflict with arch linux's convention of using python2 for python 2.7 installation.

If I modify line 50 to `which python2`, everything works perfectly and I will not see the error message whenever I launch a new shell.

What is the appropriate way of resolving this problem? Do I write an explicit check that the current OS is arch linux and introduce an if-else condition to use which python2 in virtualenvwrapper.sh and send the patch to the virtualenvwrapper author? Or is there something I can do with my configuration in my arch linux machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this arch-specific python quirk (the convention of using `python2`), I specifically create a soft link like this:-

```
ln -s /usr/bin/python2 /usr/local/bin/python
```

Since `/usr/local/bin` precedes `/usr/bin` in the bash system PATH environment variable, when I type `python`, or when the virtualenvwrapper.sh script refers to `which python` in line 50, we will no longer run into the above mentioned virtualenvwrapper conflict and everything works as expected.

The disadvantage of doing this is that it might mess up the "python 3" (being considered as the default python command) conventions arch linux is designed for.  So care has to be taken that I do not use python 3 related libraries or package installations relating to python 3 in my target box.

Comment: This is a great answer, for me it worked much better than virtualenv. I need it only sometimes thus I just create the link when needed and then unlink /usr/local/bin/python

Answer (score 3):

Virtualenvwrapper has variables `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` and `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV` which point to your python and virtualenv executables. So, in your `.bash_profile` you can write something like:

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python2
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/bin/virtualenv2
source /usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

I found there is no need to edit the `/usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` script or create a new symbolic link. I was just missing the `virtualenvwrapper` module for python2. I installed it like the following:

```
pip2 install virtualenvwrapper
```

and keeped the exports so the magic is done.